# TextEdit OnFocusChangeListener

Tags: android

I am trying to get the keyboard to come up when an editText view gets or has focus. I am getting the error `getOnFocusChangeListener in view cannot be applied to anonymous android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener`

The error starts on `new View.OnFocusChangeListener()` and goes through the whole class. I can't figure out why or how to get this working.

Here is my code:

```
final EditText measurement = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.measurement);

measurement.getOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
   @Override
   public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){
      InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      if(hasFocus){
         imm.showSoftInput(measurement, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
      }else{
         imm.showSoftInput(measurement, InputMethodManager.HIDE);
      }
   }
});
```

Please help me fill in the gaps in my knowledge about why this isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

```
 measurement.getOnFocusChangeListener
 // you have to use
 measurement.setOnFocusChangeListener
```

also you dont need to set a listener for edit text. whenever a edit text is clicked the softkeyboard will show up by itself, unless you are modifying certain behavior.

Comment: The thing is the keyboard isn't showing up when my EditTexts have/receive focus though. That is why I am trying to do it manually. I also tried my code with your fix, and no keyboard... Maybe because I am using a virtual device?